# Qual a origem e significado da expressão "fazer nas coxas"?

Tags: significado, etimologia

Exemplo de uso:

> Estava sem tempo e fiz este programa nas coxas.

O que significa isto? De onde surgiu algo que parece tão sem sentido?

Comment: Em Portugal usa-se "feito em cima do joelho"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Há algumas teorias sobre a origem desta expressão. A mais comum é mais ou menos assim (palavras minhas, pois é mais ou menos isso que eu já conhecia):

> Isso daí vem da época do Brasil colonial. Naquela época, telhas de boa qualidade eram caras, e por isso que as construções de menor importância ou provisórias utilizavam telhas de menor qualidade que pudessem ser feitas em grande quantidade e rapidamente.
>
> O processo de fabricação destas telhas era bem simples e rudimentar. Os escravos que estavam a fabricar as telhas ficavam sentados e despejavam o barro sobre as suas próprias **coxas**, utilizando então as mãos para modelar a telha e as coxas como molde. Após certo tempo, a telha era retirada de sua perna para que fosse levada ao forno.
>
> O resultado desse processo de fabricação eram telhas de baixa qualidade e tamanhos variáveis, vez que os escravos obviamente não tinham todos coxas com o mesmo tamanho e formato. Além disso, até mesmo duas telhas feitas sobre a mesma perna de um mesmo escravo em um mesmo dia apresentava variações significativas.
>
> Ao encaixar-se essas telhas para formar-se o telhado, o resultado eram telhas bem desiguais que não se encaixavam direito, ficavam irregulares, deixavam alguns buracos, ficavam tortas, desalinhadas e desniveladas. Enfim, trata-se de um telhado **feito nas coxas.**
>
> Assim, a expressão **feito nas coxas** tornou-se algo que quer dizer alguma coisa mal-feita, pois foi produzida sem zelo, de qualquer jeito, com pressa e sem preocupação com qualidade, assim como esses telhados.

Procurando no Google, você vai achar muitos sites que falam mais o menos o mesmo que digo aí em cima com minhas palavras. Entretanto, será que isso é verdade mesmo?

De acordo com [essa página](http://www.fatosdesconhecidos.com.br/de-onde-vem-a-expressao-feito-nas-coxas/) não, isso não seria verdade:

> Um estudo de caso feito pelo Professor e Arquiteto José La Pastina Filho indica que a associação entre “coxas humanas” e “telhas” não passa de boatos. As telhas feitas no Brasil colonial eram feitas em moldes de madeira.
>
> Em seu estudo de caso feito para o IPHAN do Paraná o estudioso afirma: “Para confirmar nossa convicção das inconsistências da assertiva popular – telhas feitas nas coxas dos (as) escravos (as) – tomamos as medidas das coxas de um homem de 1,80m de altura e verificamos que, usando-a como molde, só seria possível a fabricação de uma minúscula telha de 36cm de comprimento.”
>
> “Sem maiores preocupações com aspectos de anatomia humana, se estabelecermos uma simples regra de três, poderemos verificar que, para fabricar uma telha de 77 cm, precisaríamos contar com um escravo de 3,95m de altura. Além disto, em termos de otimização de força de trabalho, mesmo numa sociedade escravocrata, teríamos uma perda substancial na força de trabalho: um escravo imobilizado, com lâminas de barro sobre suas duas coxas, e pelo menos dois outros para remover cada uma delas e transportá-las ao estaleiro.”

O mesmo site relata uma outra teoria:

> Outra teoria que ganhou força nos últimos anos é que o tal “Feito nas Coxas” teria cunho sexual. A expressão originalmente significaria “sexo incompleto”. O sexo sem penetração seria comum na época pois o escândalo de uma moça virgem praticar relações sexuais antes do casamento seria terrível para uma família e para a própria pessoas na época. Assim o feito das coxas ficou conhecido como “trabalho mal feito” ou “trabalho não concluído”.

Comment: Já ouvi também que teria relação com charutos, que seriam enrolados nas coxas, e portanto terminariam co tamanho desigual e imperfeito. Talvez valha adicionar pela completude da resposta.

Comment: Em Portugal usa-se "feito em cima do joelho"

Comment: @FernandoCordeiro Acho que seria interessante você tentar colocar isso em uma resposta sua. Eu com certeza votarei a favor dela.

Answer (score 1):

É muito simples! Faça algo apoiado nas coxas: escreva uma carta apoiando o papel sobre as coxas, conserte algo delicado apoiado nas coxas...saí td mal feito, mal acabado. Só isso! Nada a ver com escravos nem com sexo!

Comment: E qual o fundamento disso? Por que não "nas canelas", "nas panturrilhas", "no ar" ou qualquer outra coisa, que sairia igualmente "mal feito" ou "mal acabado"?

Comment: Quando eu era estudante e tinha de terminar um trabalho de última hora, eu fazia em cima das coxas, no ônibus. Não fazia nas canelas, nas panturrilhas ou no ar.

Answer (score -4):

Origem da expressão “Feito nas coxas “

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rDDT.jpg)[image][image]

Comment: Fabiane, isto é muito interessante, mas mas como é que sabes que é verdade? No mínimo eu queria saber como é que os antigos gregos diziam ("fazer nas coxas" não podia ser, porque eles não falavam português), provas de que eles realmente diziam isso, e quando é que a expressão aprece na língua portuguesa.