# Qual a origem da palavra "piriguete"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, etimologia, gíria

Qual a origem da palavra [*piriguete*](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/piriguete/) (ou *periguete*)? Há alguma relação entre essa palavra e a expressão [*[estar] a perigo*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_perigo#Express.C3.B5es)? (Gíria mais antiga, e acredito que hoje em dia bem menos usada.)

Algumas definições dizem que o termo teve origem em Salvador, mas não falam muito mais sobre o mesmo. Um exemplo de [definição no Dicionário Informal](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/piriguete/1127/) (há outras):

> **Piriguete** é adjetivo e substantivo feminino, também denominada Piri, é uma gíria brasileira que designa uma mulher que troca de parceiro sexual frequentemente, normalmente jovem, de acesso fácil e/ou que tem múltiplos parceiros e tem uma preocupação excessiva em exibir os nuances do seu corpo. Geralmente anda em grupos com outras moças que compartilhem os mesmos valores.
>
> O termo teve origem em Salvador, capital da Bahia.

E sobre a expressão "a perigo" (gíria):

> - **estar a perigo**: estar necessitado de sexo ou dinheiro

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aparentemente a palavra teve sua origem na [**periferia de Salvador**](http://www.bocaonews.com.br/noticias/principal/educacao/19356,termo-piriguete-ganha-espaco-em-dicionario-aurelio.html), Bahia. A televisão incumbiu-se de divulgá-la para todo o Brasil, principalmente através das novelas, e já está incluída na [**nova edição do Aurélio**](http://www.editorapositivo.com.br/editora-positivo/dicionarios/aurelio/dicionario-aurelio.html), a ser lançada no próximo dia 11 de setembro, onde tem uma definição “mais branda”:  “moça ou mulher que não tendo namorado, apenas demonstra interesse por qualquer um”.  Da mesma forma que muitas outras gírias que chegaram e se foram com a mesma facilidade, pode ser que daqui a dez anos ninguém mais esteja usando esse termo.

> - [**Piriguete**](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/piriguete/)  - Mulher fácil, vai para baladas a procura de todos os tipos de homens para pagar tudo para elas, pois sempre saem sem dinheiro. Geralmente, quase sempre transam na primeira noite.
> - [**Piriguete**](http://www.significados.com.br/piriguete/) é **uma gíria** na língua portuguesa, considerada como um **termo pejorativo**, usado para descrever **uma mulher fútil, que só pensa em diversão e prazer.**  Periguetes são as mulheres independentes e liberais, que procuram ter várias relações sexuais sem estabelecer um critério muito assertivo para as suas escolhas.

Comment: Ok, então pelo que vejo não há relação alguma com a outra expressão. Pois segundo sua primeira referência essa palavra "é fruto da junção das palavras "perigosa" e "girl" (garota em inglês), porém o “ete” foi adaptado para dar soar melhor." Sempre estranhei a semelhança, mas pelo visto foi coisa da minha cabeça mesmo...

Comment: Essas citações são desagradavelmente preconceituosas. Particularmente a segunda, em que "mulher fútil que só pensa em diversão e prazer" é imediatamente equiparada a "mulheres independentes e liberais".

Comment: A ideia, contida no primeiro link, de que a palavra deriva de perigo+girl me parece completamente fantasiosa. Se assim fosse, seria periguel ou perigal, nunca periguete. O "g" já está em perigo, e o "irl" desaparece completamente no neologismo. Logo, se a palavra deriva de perigo - e eu não sei se é o caso - teria de ser "perigo" + "ete" (do francês, onde é diminutivo feminino), sufixo não raro no português brasileiro - garçonete, quitinete, chacrete, olavete.

Answer (score 1):

Chacrete = vedete (dançarina) do Chacrinha.

Malandrete = dançarina do Sérgio Mallandro.

Periguete = dançarina do perigo (bailes funk).

Comment: Tomás, bem-vindo à comunidade. Parece-me que pode haver nisso que escrevestes alguma coisa interessante, mas precisarias de explicar isso melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Nos anos 80 o programa do Chacrinha lançou dançarinas chamadas chacretes (chacrinha + vedetes), aí o Sérgio malandro criou as malandretes, o bolinha criou as boletes, e depois o sufixo ete virou sinônimo de dançarina.

Dito isto, as periguetes são as dançarinas do perigo, os bailes funks da periferia, cheio de bandidos armados até o dente. Daí para o termo periguete ser associado a jovens safadas, e piranhas foi um pulo.

Answer (score -1):

Desculpa mas tem uns erros na sua explicação. *Periguete* significa ’perigo inferior’.  A origem é da palavra *perigo* + -*ete*, que é sufixo e significa inferior.

Answer (score -2):

A palavra é mais sutil do que isto e mostra como o imaginário social recupera palavras antigas.

O deus Dionísio, também chamado de Baco, era chamado Pyriguenés, que significa ’nascido do fogo’. Esta é uma referência a fecundação que o deus Zeus fez com o seu raio em sua mãe Sêmele, numa referência aos ritos de hieros gamos, na qual uma mulher ou sacerdotisa era oferecida a um deus ou a um guerreiro para copular, a fim de originar uma criança sagrada.

A palavra *piriguete*, apesar de ser uma referência soteropolitana, ela traz uma origem mais antiga. Interessante, que Sêmele era uma princesa linda e desejava Zeus em todo seu esplendor, morrendo fulminada ao vê-lo, o que a fez conceber precocemente o deus Dionísio, que foi gestado na "coxa divina" de Zeus.

Interessante que as mulheres chamadas *píriguetes* acabam grávidas precocemente, muitas delas não sabendo quem é o pai, o que leva a muitos dizerem que seus filhos em geral, são feito nas "coxas". Uma forma depreciativa de sinalizar que não foi feito planejamento e a menina se deu mal.

Comment: Cláudio, bem-vindo ao site. A tese na tua resposta é muito interessante, mas deverias incluir fontes que a sustentem.

Comment: A expressão "nas coxas" não tem essa conotação sexual que você procura dar a ela. E, é claro, duvido muito que uma expressão cunhada na periferia de Salvador tenha algo a ver com mitologia grega...

Comment: Sobre a expressão "feito nas coxas", temos **[uma pergunta muito interessante](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/243/qual-a-origem-e-significado-da-express%c3%a3o-fazer-nas-coxas)** cá no portuguese.SE - que vos aconselho a lerem.